# i want to write an if else statment in access sql, i did write a code but it is not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

this is my code:

```
if (select MW 
    from Unit_tb
    where Unit_Name= Asset_tb(Unit.value)
select "true"
else 
select "false"
```

i want the Query to sum the numbers inside the table of MW if the user chose one of the units that's exists in table named Unit_tb, and U_Name field is connected with another table named asset_tb and the values of the unit table should show in a field called unit_value that i designed to be multiple.

that is in SQL IN access. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Beside _sample data and desired results_, @GordonLinoff has mentioned, note that you refer to `Unit_tb`, `U_Name` and a 'connection' (do you mean `JOIN`?) to `asset_tb`, and `unit_value `. All these are not in the code you have posted. I suggest you rewrite the code, and see how it could match your expectations

Comment: i'm new to access and SQL codes. i have searched but there isn't any clear answer if you can't please provide me with more information about how to do it accurately  that'd great.

Comment: We might be able to help if you at least provide the info requested. Edit question to show sample data and desired output.